# Query for replacing data if the value is not number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a similar problem like this thread but is bit different what it required
https://community.oracle.com/thread/4132183

I have the following table:
Table1:

```
          ID   empID     employeeactive    dtefrom    dateto        mgrid 
           1     123            1          1/10/2016                 113
           2     213             0         1/20/2015   1/20/2016     323          
           3     213             1         1/20/2016                 423
           4     312             0         1/05/2016   1/30/2017     523            
           5     512             1         1/30/2017                 623
           6     812             1         2/30/2017                 6543
```

Table2:

```
         empID           emplyactive       supid
          123               1                -
          213               1                -
          312               1                -
          512               0                -
          612               1                -
          712               1                - 
          812               1                872
          912               0                222
```

I have this table instead of - i want to replace with mgrid in table 1.. and table2 have extra data which is not in table1 so i have to ignore the extra data if supid  '-' and also want to have emplyactive =1  but some of the emplyactive=1 table 1 has multiple mgr id ...

so  I tried this one

```
      select empid , decode(supid,'-',mgrid,supid) from table2,table1 where 
         empid(+) = empid and emplyactive =1 and employeeactive=1
```

so I am getthing how to solve this please help me out thank you .. if some thing like and exists will work thanks in advance.

This is what I am trying to insert in a package body oracle.

This is how the output looks like:

```
             empID           emplyactive       supid
          123               1                   113
          213               1                   423
          812               1                   872
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.empid, a.emplyactive, max(a.supid) supid
from (
select * from #table2
union 
select empid, employeeactive, mgrid from #table1)a
left join #table1 b on a.empid=b.empid and  employeeactive=1
join #table2 c on a.empid=c.empid and  c.emplyactive=1
where a.emplyactive=1
and a.supid<>0
group by a.empid, a.emplyactive
```